# Setting up Tor Bridge on Debian VPS via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, tor

I have a currently unused budget VPS, and I'd like to contribute to the Tor Project by making it a bridge node in the network. However, I'm having trouble finding a clear and reliable guide outlining how to do this through the command line. Would anyone like to outline the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very simple.

```
echo "deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -

apt-get update

apt-get install lynx tor torsocks deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

Then check if it works:

```
usewithtor lynx http://check.torproject.org/
```

Now let's configure it for relay: just open the torrc file, and edit Relay config.

```
nano /etc/tor/torrc
```

Good luck. More info at: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I was wondering, might torify be more reliable than usewithtor, considering that the prior is provided by the Tor Project?

Comment: Additionally, is there any empirical way to test if the bridge is working? My log file contains only successful statements, but there isn't any mention of a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done what Teddy suggested, you will need to correctly edit `/etc/tor/torrc`.  Since you have specifically asked about a bridge, which doesn't publicly advertise its existence, and not a relay (which does), you will need to edit the following lines:

```
Nickname mybridge
ContactInfo Teddy Okidoki <teddy @ okidoki dot net>
DirPort 80  (this is best for bridges, since clients may have other ports blocked)
ORPort 443  (ditto)
RelayBandwidthRate 200 KB
RelayBandwidthBurst 400 KB
BridgeRelay 1
 # PublishServerDescriptor 0 (leave this commented out)
```

You will need to make sure that your firewall is set up to allow traffic to your box on ports 80 and 443.  Reload the config file.

```
/etc/init.d/tor reload
```

Read the log at /var/log/messages to make sure this is happening.

```
tail -f -n 100 /var/log/messages | grep Tor
```

You may wish to optionally subscribe to the [tor-relays mailgroup](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-relays).

Comment: Thanks. It's worth noting that on my VPS the log file was located at /var/log/tor/log.

Comment: Additionally, is there any empirical way to test if the bridge is working? My log file contains only successful statements, but there isn't any mention of a bridge.

Comment: I should also mention that the line `DirPort 80` gave the error `[warn] Can't set a DirPort on a bridge relay; disabling DirPort` on restart.

Comment: A bridge is totally hidden.  Only the Tor operators know about it.  Making it a Directory server is out of the question.  It would be like a spy standing in an information booth.  The log is in the correct place.   A good way to see if the relay is working is to install a program called "arm": https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en